# run out of memory android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

When i start and run my app on the real device its say unfortunately stopped and in the logcat says java.lang.runoutofmemory and i don't know how to fix it

Here is my main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener,
TextWatcher {


String[] category_name;
int[] category_id;
Bitmap[] pics;
GridView v1;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
// for color
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#5c7afe")));
// for image

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

v1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridvieww);
SetDB();
v1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void SetDB() {
SQLiteDatabase DB = openOrCreateDatabase("test", MODE_PRIVATE, null);// to
                                                                        // create
                                                                        // db
                                                                        // folder
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hotline_data);
try {
    byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(b);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/"
            + getPackageName() + "/databases/Hotline.sqlite");
    fos.write(b);
    fos.close();

    SQLiteDatabase hotline_db = openOrCreateDatabase("Hotline.sqlite",
            MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor c = hotline_db.rawQuery("select * from category", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        category_name = new String[c.getCount()];
        category_id = new int[c.getCount()];
        pics = new Bitmap[c.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        do {
            int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            byte[] b1 = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("pic"));
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b1, 0, b1.length);
            category_name[i] = name;
            category_id[i] = id;
            pics[i] = bm;
            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        CustomGridAdapter cga = new CustomGridAdapter(this,
                category_name, pics);
        v1.setAdapter(cga);
     }

  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

 }

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i = new Intent(this, Company.class);
i.putExtra("cat_id", category_id[arg2]);
startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

and now here's the grid view class

```
public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String [] gridValues;
private Bitmap[] pic;
public CustomGridAdapter (Context context,String[] gridValues,Bitmap[] pic){
this.context= context;
this.gridValues=gridValues;
this.pic=pic;


}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return gridValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)                                  
    View v=li.inflate(R.layout.grid, arg2, false);
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView iv=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridimage);

    iv.setImageBitmap(pic[arg0]);

    return v;
    }

    }
```

and here's the log cat

```
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    ... 41 more
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
08-20 18:09:41.738: E/AndroidRuntime(11021):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
```

need your help please quickly

Comment: Are you running it on a device or simulator?

Comment: poking for answer only 5 minutes after the post of a question may be considered rude....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to load too many bitmaps during run-time. While Android devices might have a fair amount of memory, the OS only allocates a small amount for running apps, and so you'll likely experience an OutOfMemmoryError if you hold enough.

In my app, I needed to hold a buffer of 1024x1024 images, and started getting OutOfMemory errors after about 3-4 were loaded.

One option to solve this is to set a largeHeap setting in the manifest file, however the amount of memory which is added is limited, and varies between different devices. At the end, you might be able to load a couple more images, but you'll still reach the same dead end.

The real way to solve this is to come up with a way to not require many bitmaps at once during runtime. Figure out which images you need to display on screen at any given moment and only load those. Any bitmap which isn't actually being displayed, or about to be very shortly, should be removed. When removing bitmaps, be sure to call the recycle() function on them, as this frees up the bitmap's memory instantly.

This should get you started.

Comment: ok now i must add all that bitmaps how it can be done or any other suggestion to handle this error @Gil

Comment: instead of preloading all your bitmaps, load them only when a view is assigned data via the adapter. When a view is created and assigned data, load the bitmap using AsyncTask, giving the ImageVIew some default picture until the load ends, and at the end of the load, assign the new bitmap to the ImageView. If the ImageView had a prior bitmap assigned to it, make sure to recycle it and set the ImageView's bitmap to null before beginning to load the new bitmap.

Comment: thx gil it worked with me when i increased the android heap but is that will run on another devices ?

Comment: like i said before, doing that is only going to do the trick for a bit more memory consupmtion. the problem here is that you're not using android's memory pool correctly. preloading so many bitmaps is never a good idea when writing android apps. you should always load the images you absolutely need, and immediately discard those you dont. Users will forgive not seeing the image they wanted for 1 second. They're less likely to forgive an unstable prone to crashing app.

Comment: ok thanks for your info and i will try to fix this in the new update bec. i must put it tomorrow at the store and try to download it :D (Hotlinak)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gil's response, Google provides several suggestions as to how to handle Bitmaps from the following two links:

[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and [Loading Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

This can be done with storing local version of a size accordance to the screen, manipulating inSampleSize and checking for OOM during loads to be able to respond appropriately at RunTime if you find yourself running out.

Comment: how it can be done i don't understand how it can be done